# ProGuard - Obfuscate classes name inside resource file

Tags: java, proguard, android-proguard

I'm using reflection to create classes. the classes names are located inside xml file called "classes.xml". I need to obfuscate my code using proguard. I have the following package structure:

```
/msoft/assets/classes.xml
/msoft/location/....
/msoft/fileparser/...
..
.
```

After running proguard, actual classes files are getting renamed. However, class names inside "classes.xml" are not getting renamed to match actual renamed classes files. 
One way I found to resolve this problem is to manually open the jar file, before obfuscation, copy the classes.xml to root of jar file, do obfuscation and then copy it back again. In this way classes' name inside classes.xml are getting updated. but this is an ugly way and there must be easier way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that "-adaptresourcefilecontents" option needs to be used in proguard.